# Is there any way in Python to extract last 2 character from my string column and convert it to numeric column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
QUARTER_COLUMN
FY19
FY18
FY17
```

I want extract last two characters from this column and convert it into integer type column in the same code.

```
df1['QUARTER_COLUMN'].str[-2:]
```

This will extract the character but it is not converting into integer column in the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `astype` method.

```
df1['QUARTER_COLUMN'].str[-2:].astype(int)
```

You will still need to save the returned series to the data frame.

```
df1['year'] = df1['QUARTER_COLUMN'].str[-2:].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

or simply can try using `pd.to_numeric`.

```
>>> df = df.assign(Years=df.QUARTER_COLUMN.str[-2:])
>>> df['Years'] =  pd.to_numeric(df['Years'], errors='coerce')
>>> df
  QUARTER_COLUMN  Years
0           FY19     19
1           FY18     18
2           FY17     17
```

See the dtype..

```
>>> df.dtypes
QUARTER_COLUMN    object
Years              int64
dtype: object
```

OR

Even you can try as follows assigning a column name:

```
>>> df = df.assign(Year=df.QUARTER_COLUMN.str[-2:].astype('int'))
>>> df
  QUARTER_COLUMN  Year
0           FY19    19
1           FY18    18
```

Doing through `str.extract` ..

```
>>> df = df.assign(Year=df.QUARTER_COLUMN.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True).astype(int))
>>> df
  QUARTER_COLUMN  Year
0           FY19    19
1           FY18    18
2           FY17    17
```